# how can i make an android view grow dynamically when i add text in it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have an android `LinearLayout` with a background image (9 patch). Inside the Layout there is a `TextView`.

How can I make the textView and its parent respectively when the text has more content

(as a result of translation and localization) ?

Comment: You can add your TextView in ScrollView.Also it should be better to use wrap_content for height of TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to use "wrap_content" as width and height.